# How do I clean the farthest molars without invoking gag reflex?

Tags: personal-care

It's been pain since I started cleaning teeth properly.

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks! You could improve the quality of your question and increase the chance of receiving more answers if you explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: I had that kind of problem too, even at the dentist, and it came down and down as time passed... Still more sensible with that than most people, but not to the point I can't bruch my teeth...

Answer (score 3):

With your left hand, make a fist with your thumb inside. This somehow suppresses the gag reflex and allows the cleaning of the farthest molars or the tongue. Be cautious, though.

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks.SE. This is a very interesting idea, if it does indeed work. Do you know why this works or have any sources supporting it?

Comment: This does indeed work.  I use this when going to the dentist as well.  I've had dentists take x-rays of my teeth and they are trying to rush through it because most people have a gag reflex during this time.  I used this technique and passed it onto the dentist so they could help others could benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a small headed toothbrush - I have a similar problem to yours, and I use two brushes to clean my teeth, one is the smallest possible standard headed brush, but the other has a very small head, and that's the one I employ when doing right at the back of the mouth. Actually, its a child's brush, because I couldn't find a small enough head in the adult range in the store at the time. Corsyodyl make a small headed, oval shaped brush, and that one's okay, Amazon sells them in soft or medium. The alternative is an electric toothbrush with a round headed brush, such as most of the Oral B range has, but if the interior oral cavity is small (as is mine) I find it quite difficult to manouevre a clunky electric handle and stem within the mouth to cover all surfaces.